# Linux installation freezes after system checking disk is done

Tags: software-installation

I know some things about the command prompt of linux and I want to install linux OS. I am trying to do this by installing it kn a usb. So I downloaded the .iso file (ubuntu) and I installed it in the usb using rufus. I am new to linux so I am sorry if something that I said, is not correct. After this I changed the boot and I put the usb on the top of the boot list and I boot. After this I wait for the check to finish and when it does, it freezes. I dont know what to so...I searched everywhere and I tried some things but I still couldn't fix it...My screen is stuck like this:

[The screen is stuck like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgSBW.jpg)

The Grub menu is :

[Grub-Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpvqp.jpg)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS. Thanks for the response!!